# Prove that $\mathbb{R}^\times\times\mathbb{R}^\times\ncong\mathbb{C}^\times$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

As the title says, prove that the direct product of real number with real number with respect to multiplication is not isomorphic to complex numbers with respect to multiplication. I proved in the last part that $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\cong\mathbb{C}$, but I don't know how to progress to this part. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to think about how many elements satisfy the equation $x^2 = 1$. (The fancy name for this is to consder the ''two-torsion'' of the multiplicative groups.)

In $\mathbb C$ there are two solutions, $x = 1$ and $-1$. In $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ there are more -- do you see why?

---

You can also try the same thing with 3-torsion: how many elements satsify $x^3 = 1$ in each case?

Comment: in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ there are 4 since we have we can have $(1,-1),(-1,1),(1,1),(-1,-1)$ right?

Comment: also, we haven't covered torsion groups so I don't really know what it is.

Comment: that's right. it's ok if you haven't learned about torsion yet, you just need to understand what $x^2 = 1$ means, or $x^3 = 1$

Answer (score 2):

Find an element of $\mathbb{C}$ that behaves differently under multiplication than any real number. Like $\mathfrak{i}$, perhaps. What properties does $\mathfrak{i}$ have under multiplication? Is there an element of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ that behaves like $\mathfrak{i}$? Nope.

Comment: E.g. $i^4$ is the multiplicative unit.

Comment: So in $\mathbb{C}$ there is an element that is not the identity element that, when multiplied by itself by 4 times, becomes the identity element. Given that, I can set out to find a similar element in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ and (hopefully) fail. Correct?

Comment: @user539807 Yep, that's the idea. So you need to show that no element of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ has order four. Showing this, though, sounds kinda like a tougher approach than what [Harry did in their answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2690364/167197).